# How can i build animated counter with python bokeh?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I am currently studying python bokeh and i was wondering if it is possible to build an animated counter using bokeh. What i am trying to do is pull number of males from a selected district in the map and display the number running from 0 to the number of males in the particular district . Please show me some examples if any or use the map below to show me an  example.

```
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import pandas as pd 


with open('ug_population.geo.json','r') as f:
    geojson = f.read()

geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=geojson)

def build_map():

    mp = figure(height=600, width=600,tools="tap", title="Click the District")
    mp.patches(xs='xs' , ys='ys',fill_color = "#EBE02A",fill_alpha=0.7, source=geo_source)
    mp.multi_line(xs='xs', ys='ys', line_color='white', line_width=0.1, source=geo_source)
    mp.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("District", "@name"),("Total Population","@total")]))

    return mp


mp = build_map()
show(mp)
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.The jsonfile used can be found here [Pastebin of json file](http://pastebin.com/fDMygtgn)

Comment: Adding animations and transitions to standalone documents is on our fairly near-term roadmap, but it is not yet implemented as of the `0.11.1` release. For now, there are basically two options: i) use the Bokeh server, or ii) resort to a custom HTML template with a bit of JavaScript to make the animation

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I will try it out using bokeh server. Great tool by the way, keep up the good work.